# Using ldap locally to share login info with webapps - Do I need Kerberos too?

Tags: ldap, debian, kerberos, authentication, openldap

So I'm setting up a dedicated server using Debian 5 Lenny. I will be using some Atlassian Tools (JIRA, Confluence, Bamboo, and Fisheye). I want to use a local LDAP server to store information for the users that will be accessing these software titles, so that they can use one set of credentials to log in.

I also want webmail users to be configured using LDAP.

However, this is a small operation. Three people. That's why all of the software, including the ldap server, will all be on the same machine.

That said, is it safe to use LDAP to store user credentials (including passwords) in LDAP without using Kerberos? I'm confused as to when Kerberos should be used.

Hypothetically, let's say I had two servers on a subnet. Server A received requests from the outside world, for atlassian tools. Server a communicates to ldap server (internally) on server b. In that case, would I use kerberos?

When do I use Kerberos? When do I not?

I am not setting anything like "Active Directory" up. No Samba either. Users do not need to login to a domain (with access to files on the domain), they just need to login to webapps. But if I was doing LDAP on it's own dedicated machine, then I might want Kerberos?

:confuzzled: :(

-Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest possible answer is yes, it is possible to store user names, user ids, and passwords without using Kerberos, and in fact directory services accessed via LDAP are an excellent tool for storing this sort of authentication and authorization information.

Update:

In my opinion, if you do choose an open source server, you will find OpenDS to be superior to OpenLDAP or Apache.

Comment: what about OpenDS is superior to OpenLDAP? there are mountains of information available about openldap. So you're essentially advocating that I can use LDAP for everything locally without Kerberos? What about if I had internal communication (let's say 15 users, website running on main box, auth handled by separate smaller box). Now it's not all local. Then should I use Kerberos to protect traffic being sent in the subnet?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you have Kerberos, you do not need any directory server. If you aren't in a corporate environment and are looking for an identity management store, you should definitively go for a directory server like OpenLDAP or Apache Directory. Kerberos require running a correctly set up DNS and NTP server. This might be way to much. Even if you do, those lazy morons from Atlassian still did not implement Kerberos support into their products. You can't even go with that.

I just noticed that there are only three of you, maybe a simple database setup with MySQL would suffice instead of running a full-blown directory server?

Comment: this is a learning experience as much as it is anything else. want to make sure I'm teaching myself how to create a secure network (internal and external) for agile enterprise development